# I'm getting the "null check operator used on a null value" and the "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform" at same time

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing a flutter app to collect the nearby ATMs and show the user in the app. So I first get the cuurent location of the user as seen in the code above then i tried to use geoflutterfire to query cloud firestore for nearby ATMs within  a certain radius. The code is as follows. When I comment the line
`GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(latitude: position1!.latitude, longitude: position1!.longitude);`
the null safety error goes

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/cloud_firestore_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gab/pages/functions.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


final geo = Geoflutterfire();
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;



class Principal extends StatefulWidget {
  const Principal({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Principal> createState() => _PrincipalState();
}

class _PrincipalState extends State<Principal> {

  //To obatin positon
  Position? position1;
  getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position = await determinePosition();
    setState(() {
      position1 = position;
    });
  }
  Future<Position> determinePosition() async {
    LocationPermission permission;
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied){
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied){
        return Future.error("Location permissions are denied");
      }
    }
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    getCurrentLocation();
    GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(latitude: position1!.latitude, longitude: position1!.longitude);//There is an erro here. the null check operator used on a null value!
     // GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(latitude: 4.0908151, longitude: 9.8037623);
     // _firestore.collection('atms').add({'bank': 'test', 'isFunctioning': true,'position':point.data});
    var collectionReference  = _firestore.collection('atms').where("isFunctioning", isEqualTo: true);
    double radius = 1000;
    String field = 'position';
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
        .within(center: point, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true);


    stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
      // print("Here");
      // print(documentList[0].data());
    });
     return Scaffold(

       //TRY Not Working
       body: SafeArea(
         child: StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
           stream: stream,
           builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot){
             if(!snapshot.hasData){
               return Container(
                 child: Text("No data"),
               );
             }
             return Container(
               child: ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                   itemBuilder: ((context, index){
                 DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data![index];
                 GeoPoint documentLocation = data.get('location');
                 var distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(point.latitude, point.longitude,
                     documentLocation.latitude, documentLocation.longitude);
                 print('${distanceInMeters}');
                 return ListTile(
                   title: Text('${data.get('bank')}'),
                   subtitle: Text('${distanceInMeters}'),

                 );
               })),
             );
           },
         ),
       ),

     );
  }
}
```

And then i get the errors as seen in the pictures. I also sho how I designed the cloud firestore
[image: This is for the null cheeck operator used on a null value]

[image: This is for the bad state: field doesnot exist with the DocumentSnapshotPlatform]

[image: This is my cloud firestore]

Comment: It's something about futures, and making promises that something won't be null when it is.  Be sure to await your futures, and don't use the null check unless you're absolutely sure.

Comment: Thanks I solved that by putting in an ''if''. My problem now is to solve the ''bad state problem''